# Why most of the books give Definite Integral Represents Area Under the curve

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

According to my understanding The definition of Definite Integral is:

if $f(x)$ is a Continuous function in $[a \:\: b]$ and if $P$ is Partition of the Interval $[a \:\: b]$ Then

$$ \lim _{\lVert P \rVert \to 0}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(c_k)\Delta x_k=\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx$$ Definite Integral can be negative positive or zero and its value may or may not represent area under the curve.

For example $$\int_{0}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}} \cos x \:dx=-1$$

But the area of $f(x)=\cos x$ in $[0 \: \frac{3\pi}{2}]$ is

$$A=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos x\:dx+\left|\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}\cos x \:dx\right|=1+|-2|=3$$

Hence Area of a curve $f(x)$ is given by $$A=\int_{a}^{b} |f(x)|dx$$
so area always represents definite Integral of a Positive function.

But why books give the reverse statement that Definite Integral represents area under the curve.

Answer (score 1):

I think a lot of calculus books use vague terminology to not confuse a frustrated student even more. The difference between the two things you mention is just a matter of what you are using the integral for. Typically, in a calculus course you are finding area or volume and so you use geometric area. However, sometimes you do line-integrals, where you just take the signed area i.e whatever # the integral gives. Hopefully this helps a bit. Maybe someone can share on this. I tried not to give paragraphs of explanation.